# SVG Animate bouncing arrow

Tags: svg

I have the following SVG:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 50 38.7" enable-background="new 0 0 50 38.7" xml:space="preserve">

<polygon fill="#08B2EF" points="49.4,14.6 25.4,1.2 0.6,14.6 11.1,14.6 7.5,36.2 42.5,36.2 38.5,14.6 " />

</svg>
```

I want to make this animated - so that the arrow is bouncing like a "This way"

I have looked online and I can't seem to find any examples that does this. Can anyone suggest a way of doing this? Not using jQuery or CSS just pure SVG?

EDIT:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 50 38.7" enable-background="new 0 0 50 38.7" xml:space="preserve">

<polygon fill="#08B2EF" points="49.4,14.6 25.4,1.2 0.6,14.6 11.1,14.6 7.5,36.2 42.5,36.2 38.5,14.6 ">

<animateMotion path="M 0 0 V 300 Z" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</polygon>
</svg>
```

As you can see, the arrow leaves the screen and does not come back for some time. I just need it to bounce up and down and not leave the screen??

Comment: Use a SMIL animateTransform to animate a translate on the polygon.

Comment: @RobertLongson Do you have an example, sorry? I followed the tutorial for your suggestion: `<animateMotion path="M 0 0 H 300 X" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" />` I just need the animation to go up instead of across?

Comment: V 300 instead of H 300 then

Comment: @RobertLongson Nearly there - https://jsfiddle.net/ Just don't want it to leave the screen, so it like bounces and does not leave the screen? Any ideas (Sorry, SVG is not my strong point)

Comment: @RobertLongson Updated question. Hopefully that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to move less, adjust the V so it doesn't go as far.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 50 38.7" enable-background="new 0 0 50 38.7" xml:space="preserve">

<polygon fill="#08B2EF" points="49.4,14.6 25.4,1.2 0.6,14.6 11.1,14.6 7.5,36.2 42.5,36.2 38.5,14.6 ">

<animateMotion path="M 0 0 V 20 Z" dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</polygon>
</svg>
```